# Modernizr 2 enabled blank pages in several browsers

Tags: css, html, javascript, modernizr

I've been testing libraries for enabling HTML5 and loading JavaScript. I'm experiencing some oddities with **modernizer 2** in IE7, Firefox 4 on XP, and others. (Works fine in IE6 and 8)

When including the script the browser simply **renders the screen blank white**.

http://ibob.dk/velkommen-narrow-head-modrn.html

I've managed to get it to show content if removing all styling. However scrolling down causes the browser to smear the content.

I see no JavaScript or HTML interpretation errors. Anyone got a hint to what is going on?

Comment: If I use the ‘barebone’ script. Just clicking generate from http://www.modernizr.com/download/. That custom script will work. So hast to be something in CSS HTML5 detection that breaks it (?)

Comment: Could it be a security issue?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, very interested if any answers are found.

Comment: I didn’t find a solution yet.

Comment: I've opened an issue on modernizr on github https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/361

Answer (score 1):

Resolved on github importing last version of modernizr
REad Michael link:
*"I've opened an issue on modernizr on github github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/361 – Michael"*

Comment: Yes, I did that. Installing the latest version worked. Didn't exist at the time, though :(